# Powershell what does Function script: functionname do? Especially the script: part

Tags: powershell

I was looking at the posh-git code and I found the author doing this.

`function script:gitCmdOperations($command, $filter)`

Needless to say I didn't find anything on google about this.

What I am looking for is why he used the script: part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It defines the function's scope to be the script scope. See: `help about_scopes`

Comment: But then why can I still call it from my script when I use dot-sourcing?

Comment: I'm guessing that that external script then becomes part of my script and thus still in the script scope.

Comment: Correct, dot-sourcing brings the script into the current scope.

Comment: It should be noted that script: scope doesn't make any difference for functions that are right in the script.  But it does make a different for nested functions.

Answer (score 4):

It's a way to create a function at a specific scope (using scope modifier). Take this for example:

```
function outer {
   ...
   function inner { ... }
}
```

In the above example , function inner is only available inside the outer function (local scope). What if you wanted to create inner in the global scope, so when your script has finished, the inner function will still be available? You use the scope modifier:

```
function outer {
   ...
   function global:inner { ... }
}
```

Check the about_Scopes help files for more information